# How do I sort a QStandardItemModel and QListView by checked objects?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to sort my ListView Model by checked objects. In the example below I've tried to add a `self.model.sort()`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect *except for Qt.AscendingOrder*, which was recently revealed to me.

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html) says "You can search for items in the model with findItems(), and sort the model by calling sort()", but only `self.model.sort(QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)` seems to actually have an effect.

Do I misunderstand?

The GUI below set to launch whatever code is in the `print_checked_items()` after a set amount of time.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWizardPage, QListView


class AppRemovalPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        super(AppRemovalPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list_view = QListView(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.list_view)

        for line in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'):
            self.item = QtGui.QStandardItem(line)
            self.item.setCheckable(True)
            self.item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.model.appendRow(self.item)

        self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.list_view.clicked.connect(self.getSelectedListItem)
        self.list_view.show()


    def print_checked_items(self):
        self.model.sort(QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder) # has no effect

        for index in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            item = self.model.item(index)
            if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                print(item.text(), "was checked")
        print("rerun timed script to list checked objects again")


    def getSelectedListItem(self):
        currentSelection = self.list_view.selectedIndexes()

        name  = None
        row   = None
        index = None

        # Set name for currently selected object in listview
        for obj_index in currentSelection:
            item  = self.model.itemFromIndex(obj_index)
            row   = item.row()
            index = self.model.index(row, 0)
            name  = self.model.data(index)

        self.currName  = name
        self.currRow   = row
        self.currIndx  = index


app = QApplication([])
listview = AppRemovalPage(None)
listview.show()
QTimer.singleShot(4000, listview.print_checked_items)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It is not clear what is wrong? 
Add a couple of elements to the model, for example ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a2', 'a1').

Comment: Okay, so I *can* apparently sort in ascending order. But seemingly not in any other way.

Comment: Qt.DescendingOrder The items are sorted descending e.g. starts with ‘ZZZ’ ends with ‘AAA’ in Latin-1 locales

Comment: `self.model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)` and `self.model.sort(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)` works. Is that the correct approach? It seems a bit... reverse.